# Flat rate shipping option totally ignored

Tags: shipping, ce-1.9.1.1, flat

I have only one shipping method in my shop. $3.99 flat rate. Everything else is set to not be enabled.

Does anyone know why Magento would just ignore this shipping rule and apply what I can only imagine as a totally random $2.99 per item flat rate rule that is set nowhere in the cms?

I had some shipping plugins enabled once upon a time but they never really worked out. I have disabled them by going to app/module/xxx.xml and setting `<active>` to false, which appears to have removed the plugins from the admin. And when I say they never worked out I mean they did nothing. The plugins were so badly documented I never figured out how to set up their tiered systems and what have you. Only one I had working was USPS using their calculator, which is now disabled.

I cleared both standard caches in the cache management panel.

This is the only shipping option enabled:
[image: This is the only shipping option enabled]

This is the cart.
2 items x $2.99 = $5.98... clearly NOT $3.99 for this order, but yet you can see the Flat Rate - Fixed so it seems like it is pulling the name of this rule, just not the price or actual rule:
[image: 2 items x $2.99 = $5.98... clearly NOT $3.99 for this order]

Magento 1.9.1.1 if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swear I've been working on this for hours and no sooner than the second I posted this did I realize I had to select current configuration scope to the domain and not default... why does it have default AND domain in there when I have only one site? well, that's another question. For now, this is the answer in case someone else had a similar issue.

Thanks for reading my waste of your time.